# How can I use Chatter in an external Web Site?

Tags: chatter

Is it possible to integrate Chatter module in an external website?
The goal is to use Chatter in an external web site and can create post about one document or custom object.

I can add Chatter component in a Salesforce Visual Page, but not in an external web site designed with ASP.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean by "external"? You can utilize chatter through Communities which can then be made available to guest users outside your organization via a portal.

Comment: external web site like www.company.com in external server

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Chatter REST API to access Chatter but you will need a user context with which to access / post information.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/

If your intention is merely to display a read only chatter feed then you can get away with an integration user and use the Chatter REST API to display the feed.

If you however want users to be able to post you will need to take care of the authentication via oauth or similar and then have salesforce users set up for all those who intend accessing.

If the users of this external website and Single Signed into Salesforce you could probably get away with embedding an Iframe which uses their already established session with salesforce to display a Chatter Feed